# sql syntax error storing html table as text in mysql

Tags: html, mysql, sql

Query to insert text in database is:

INSERT INTO uri VALUES('')

I'm getting follwing Syntax error:

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
  `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL     server version for the right syntax to use near 'liq" style="font-size:110%;font-family:'Alvi Nastaleeq', 'Nafees Nastaleeq', 'Na' at line 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
    title=\"Nasta'liq\"
                 ^-----you have single quote alone here .get rid of it
```

to

```
  title=\"Nasta liq\"
```

or

```
  title=\"Nastaliq\"
```

Comment: thanx but problem is that this value comes from a webpage and is dynamic this is not hardcoded query should i remove using some regular expression?

Comment: you have also `پاکست"ان`  error you should use it `پاکستان`. wrong double quote there

Comment: yes but there's also an error of single quotes here "font-size:110%;font-family:'Alvi Nastaleeq', 'Nafees Nastaleeq', 'Na'